# How InMemoryTokenStore works with Spring Security OAuth2 and Is this the safest way from hacking perspective?

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am new to `Spring Security OAuth2` using version `2.0.10.RELEASE` implementation. I developed code using `'InMemoryTokenStore'` and I'm impressed with the way it works (it creates `access_token`, `'refresh_token'` etc..), but I don't have enough understanding on how it works yet. Can anyone please help to know / provide understanding on how it works?

Is `'InMemoryTokenStore'` the safest implementation from hacking perspective? I also see there are many implementation provided by OAuth2 like `JdbcTokenStore`, `JwtTokenStore`,`KeyStoreKeyFactory`. I don't think storing `access_token` into the database in the great idea like `JdbcTokenStore` does.

Which Implementation we should follow and why ?

**spring-security-oauth2.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd ">


    <http pattern="/oauth/token" auto-config="true" use-expressions="true"  create-session="stateless"  authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" > 

        <!-- <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" /> -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="permitAll" />
        <anonymous enabled="false" />
        <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
        <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" /> 
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
        <!-- Added this to fix error -->
        <sec:csrf disabled="true" />
    </http>

    <http pattern="/resources/**" auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" create-session="never" entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <anonymous enabled="false" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" method="GET" />
        <!-- <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" /> -->
        <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
        <!-- Added this to fix error -->
        <sec:csrf disabled="true" />
    </http>

    <http pattern="/logout" create-session="never"  auto-config="true" use-expressions="true"
        entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <anonymous enabled="false" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/logout" method="GET" />
        <sec:logout invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/logout" success-handler-ref="logoutSuccessHandler"   />
        <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
        <!-- Added this to fix error -->
        <sec:csrf disabled="true" />
    </http>

    <bean id="logoutSuccessHandler" class="demo.oauth2.authentication.security.LogoutImpl" >
        <property name="tokenstore" ref="tokenStore"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    </bean>

    <bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="realmName" value="springsec/client" />
        <property name="typeName" value="Basic" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler">
    </bean>

    <bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    </bean>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
    </authentication-manager>

    <bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
        <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="clientDetails" class="demo.oauth2.authentication.security.ClientDetailsServiceImpl"/>

    <authentication-manager id="userAuthenticationManager" 
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <authentication-provider  ref="customUserAuthenticationProvider">
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <bean id="customUserAuthenticationProvider"
        class="demo.oauth2.authentication.security.CustomUserAuthenticationProvider">
    </bean>

    <oauth:authorization-server
        client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices">
        <oauth:authorization-code />
        <oauth:implicit/>
        <oauth:refresh-token/>
        <oauth:client-credentials />
        <oauth:password authentication-manager-ref="userAuthenticationManager"/>
    </oauth:authorization-server>

    <oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter"
        resource-id="springsec" token-services-ref="tokenServices" />

    <!-- <bean id="tokenStore"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.InMemoryTokenStore" /> -->

    <bean id="tokenStore"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.InMemoryTokenStore" />

    <bean id="tokenServices" 
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
        <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
        <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
        <property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="300000"></property>
        <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
    </bean>


    <mvc:annotation-driven />   <!-- Declares explicit support for annotation-driven MVC controllers  @RequestMapping, @Controller -->

    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />

    <bean id="MyResource" class="demo.oauth2.authentication.resources.MyResource"></bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 25):

You're mixing in several things together. InMemoryTokenStore, JwtTokenStore and JdbcTokenStore are only supposed to be used for different cases. There is no such a thing which of them is safer and which is not.

### JwtTokenStore

> **JwtTokenStore** encodes token-related data into the token itself. **It does not make tokens persistent** and requires JwtAccessTokenConverter as a translator between a JWT-encoded token
>   and OAuth authentication information. ("Spring Essentials" by Shameer Kunjumohamed, Hamidreza Sattari).

The important thing is that tokens are not persisted at all and validated "on the fly" based on signature.

> One disadvantage is that **you can't easily revoke an access token**, so they normally are granted with short expiry and the revocation is handled at the refresh token. Another disadvantage is that the tokens can get quite large if you are storing a lot of user credential information in them. The JwtTokenStore is not really a "store" in the sense that it doesn't persist any data. [read more](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html)

### InMemoryTokenStore

**InMemoryTokenStore** stores tokens in server memory so it's hardly possible to share them among different servers. You'll lose all access tokens in InMemoryTokenStore when you restart your authorisation server. I'd prefer to use InMemoryTokenStore only during development and not in a production environment.

> The default InMemoryTokenStore is perfectly fine for a single server (i.e. low traffic and no hot swap to a backup server in the case of failure). Most projects can start here, and maybe operate this way in development mode, to make it easy to start a server with no dependencies. [read more](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html)

### JdbcTokenStore

> The **JdbcTokenStore** is the JDBC version of the same thing, which stores token data in a relational database. Use the JDBC version if you can share a database between servers, either scaled up instances of the same server if there is only one, or the Authorization and Resources Servers if there are multiple components. To use the JdbcTokenStore you need "spring-jdbc" on the classpath. [read more](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html)

In case of JdbcTokenStore you're saving the tokens in real database. So you're safe in case of Authorization service restart. The tokens can be also easily shared among the servers and revoked. But you have more dependancies for database.